# UPS users and groups

Tags: profile-sync

Trying to get an idea of this concept of groups when it comes to UPS.
We have groups in AD that we use for security in SharePoint 2013. Will excluding groups from UPS affect this?
Only interested in syncing users but do not want to jeopardise the security we have setup within SP2013.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the UPS is there to provide support for richer user profile information for individuals or groups and some of the 2013 social features.  Excluding the AD groups from the sync should only mean that the AD groups won't be imported or returned in places like people search and should not affect the way security behaves.  Security is still driven by standard authentication which is filtered via SharePoint groups/permissions or AD so the UPS shouldn't interfere with this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have seen cases where groups, if not selected in UPS sync, does not get imported to SharePoint. This means that you can not use them as audiences in views and webparts. Quite strange